# how to make multilingual (localization) in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, localization, multilingual

I have tried to create localization in laravel as well as given in laravel official documentation and it worked like charm!! However it works only for single request. I want it to work for all requests until user changes language.
how to create multilingual site in laravel not only for single request as given in laravel documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all we need to write few anchor tags (use yours: in your home.blade.php page) to switch language like below...

```
    <a href="{{url('change/locale/en')}}">ENGLISH</a>
    <a href="{{url('change/locale/fr')}}">FRENCH</a>
    <a href="{{url('change/locale/uz')}}">UZBEK</a>
```

then we need to create following Route like below to accept requests...

```
    Route::get('change/locale/{lang}', function($lang){
        Session::put('locale', $lang);
        return redirect()->back();
    });
```

next step is to run this command in your terminal to create middleware named `LanguageMiddleware`

```
    php artisan make:middleware LanguageMiddleware
```

after that lets open our `LanguageMiddleware` that we created into app/Http/Middleware folder and replace this couple of code with handle method

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    if ( Session::has('locale')) {
        App::setLocale(Session::get('locale'));
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

now add this line

```
\App\Http\Middleware\LanguageMiddleware::class
```

into `Kernel.php -> protected $middlewareGroups -> web`

and create folders called
 `en` , `uz` , `fr` into `views/lang` folder.
then create `messages.php` file in every folder we created above `(en,fr,uz)`

now your folders must look just like this.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

now you can call your dictionary like this

```
@lang('messages.greeting')
```

that's end ! now you can check it by clicking on your anchor tags that we created in first step.

Comment: Not sure of the point of this post when it follows closely to answers that already exist on this site.